# How to use xt::repeat?

Tags: c++, xtensor

I want to get repeated array same way as `numpy` but `xt::repeat` returns expression. When I try to cast this expression to array, I'm getting compile error.

```
xt::array<int> a = {{1, 2}, {3, 4}};
auto r = xt::repeat(a, 3, 1); // r is expression
xt::array<int> b = r; // compile error here
```

How to repeat array and get result as another array not expression? Maybe I miss something in documentation but I can not find working example.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that's a bug: https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/issues/1989

Comment: @TomdeGeus please post answer when this bug will be solved

Comment: It seems it was solved in version [0.21.5](https://xtensor.readthedocs.io/en/latest/changelog.html#id117), with PR [1993](https://github.com/xtensor-stack/xtensor/pull/1993)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in `xtensor`. I am working on a patch, for now you can use the following workaround:

```
xt::xarray<int> b(r.shape());
std::copy(r.cbegin(), r.cend(), b.begin());
```